# Using conditionalPanel (or other methods) to create a temporary banner that disappears if user navigates away

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I want to create a welcome message for when a user first opens the shiny webpage. Currently I have it such that it is constantly on the first tabPanel. Is there a way to make it disappear when the user navigates away and then back to that panel?

```
fluidRow(
  column(width=12,
         tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",  id = "tabs1", 
                     tabPanel("Express Usage", wellPanel("Welcome! Please select the libraries you are interested in viewing from below and use the tabs to navigate between graphs. It is best to limit your selection to no more than 5 libraries at a time"), plotOutput("express_Plot", height=400)),
                     tabPanel("Juvenile Usage", plotOutput("juvenile_Plot", height=400)), 
                     tabPanel("test", h3(textOutput("text_test")))))
  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `value` attribute for all your `tabPanel`s accordingly. 
In this way, you can tell, in **server.R**, which tab is currently selected by reading `input$tabs1`, where `tabs1` is the `id` you set for the `tabsetPanel`.

Replace the `wellPanel` with a `uiOutput` element, and update the UI elements according 
to:

1. The current panel.
2. The times the panel has been visited.

#### ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width=12,
           tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",  id = "tabs1", 
                       tabPanel("Express Usage", 
                                uiOutput("welcome"), # replace the wellPanel
                                plotOutput("express_Plot", height=400), value="ex_usage"),
                       tabPanel("Juvenile Usage", plotOutput("juvenile_Plot", height=400), value="juv_usage"), 
                       tabPanel("test", h3(textOutput("text_test")))), value="test")
  )
)
)
```

#### server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  visits <- reactiveValues(times = 0)
  output$welcome <- renderUI({
    if (input$tabs1 == "ex_usage") {
      isolate(visits$times <- visits$times + 1)
      if (isolate(visits$times) == 1) {
        return (wellPanel("Welcome! Please select the libraries you are interested in viewing from below and use the tabs to navigate between graphs. It is best to limit your selection to no more than 5 libraries at a time"))
      }
      else {
        return ()
      }
    }
  })
})
```